# Why does .PHONY not work in this situation?

Tags: makefile

I have a complicated makefile that seems to relink my libraries and executables every time I invoke it.  I was able to narrow down the problem into a simple makefile:

```
 1: all: prog
 2:
 3: .PHONY: prog
 4: prog: prog.exe
 5:
 6: prog.exe: lib prog.o
 7:         touch prog.exe
 8:
 9: prog.o: prog.c
10:         touch prog.o
11:
12: .PHONY: lib
13: lib: lib.so
14:
15: lib.so: lib.o
16:         touch lib.so
17:
18: lib.o: lib.c
19:         touch lib.o
20:
21: .PHONY: clean
22: clean:
23:         rm *.so *.o *.exe
```

For some reason, this example, prog.exe is created every time.  If I replace the lib on line 6 with lib.so then it works.  Yet it seems like I should be able to do what I'm attempting here.  Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the online GNU make manual:

> A phony target should not be a
>   prerequisite of a real target file; if
>   it is, its recipe will be run every
>   time make goes to update that file. As
>   long as a phony target is never a
>   prerequisite of a real target, the
>   phony target recipe will be executed
>   only when the phony target is a
>   specified goal (see Arguments to
>   Specify the Goals).

That at least explains what you are seeing.  Since `prog.exe` depends on `lib`, your phony target for collecting libraries, the `lib` rule is fired, and hence `prog.exe` is "out of date", and gets relinked.

It looks like you'll have to be more explicit about your dependencies.  Perhaps you would be interested in putting them in a variable to make managing multiple libraries a bit easier?  For example:

```
LIBS = lib.so

all: libs progs

.PHONY: progs libs clean

progs: prog.exe

prog.exe: $(LIBS) prog.o
    touch prog.exe

# etc.
libs: $(LIBS)

lib.so: lib.o
    touch lib.so

# and so on
```

In the above example, I've also changed the names of the phony targets to `progs` and `libs`, which in my experience are more common.  In this case, the `libs` target is just a convenience for building all the libraries, rather than acting as an actual dependency.

Comment: I wish they let you do that.  My makefiles allow my "customers" to specify dependencies to other libraries without the lib*.so.  So if they have an exe called MyProg that depends on MyLib1 and MyLib2, then they would just say: "LIB_FILES:=MyLib1 MyLib2" rather than "LIB_FILES:=<location>/libMyLib1.so <location>/libMyLib2.so".  I guess I need to store off the actual name and location of the libs so that this will work.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: How do I "accept the answer"?  Also, I tried to click the up arrow, but it says I need 15 reputation.  I'm new here, so I guess I'm a person of ill repute on this site. :(

Comment: As far as the upvote thing goes, as you get more reputation points you'll be able to do more things, like upvoting a question.  I'd suggest reading the FAQ (there is a link at the top of every page) to get a better idea of how SO is run.

Comment: I created a related post here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810943/i-want-my-makefile-to-be-more-order-independent

I would appreciate any time you can give!