# I Want my makefile to be more order independent!

Tags: makefile

This is related to my previous question: [Why does .PHONY not work in this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787686/why-does-phony-not-work-in-this-situation).

I have a makefile system that I wrote to make it easy for developers who are not familiar with make, to do their tasks.  In short, there is a generic portion which would be the same for all projects, and a set of makefiles that are specific for a given project.  The project specific ones include the generic ones.  It worked great on make 3.80 for some reason, but when I tried it out on make 3.81 I ran into a few problems.  That forced me to make changes that are mentioned in the above post.  Now I have some new problems, so I decided to make another post.  Like in that post, I made a much smaller and simpler set of makefiles that show the problem.  Unfortunatly, the "simple" case consists of 6 files.  Sorry about that.  First I'll start with the "project specific" ones (these are meant to be simple):

**makefile:**

```
TARGETS:=\
    Lib1.mk \
    Lib2.mk \
    my_prog.mk \

include generic/top.mk
```

**Lib1.mk:**

```
BINARY:=Lib1
TYPE:=LIB
LOCATION:=a/location

include generic/rules.mk
```

**Lib2.mk:**

```
BINARY:=Lib2
TYPE:=LIB
LOCATION:=another/location
LIBS:=Lib1

include generic/rules.mk
```

**my_prog.mk:**

```
BINARY:=my_prog
TYPE:=EXE
LOCATION:=some/location
LIBS:=Lib1 Lib2

include generic/rules.mk
```

A quick description: Makefile simply lists the names of all the targets.  A target is either a executable or a library.  BINARY is the name of the library or executable (extensions are added by the generic part).  TYPE is either EXE or LIB.  LOCATION is where the binary should go.  LIBS is whatever libraries this binary depends on.  The real ones handles creating all the -L, rpath, etc. stuff for the user (as well as their equivalents for visual studio).  Now for the generic ones (these do the REAL work):

**generic/top.mk:**

```
ALL_BINS:=

.PHONY: all
all:

include $(TARGETS)

all: $(ALL_BINS)

%.so %.exe:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -rf out
```

and finally..

**generic/rules.mk:**

```
ifeq (EXE,$(TYPE))
$(BINARY).FULL_FILE_NAME:=out/$(LOCATION)/$(BINARY).exe
else
$(BINARY).FULL_FILE_NAME:=out/$(LOCATION)/lib$(BINARY).so
endif

$(BINARY).DEP_LIBS:=$(foreach a,$(LIBS),$($(a).FULL_FILE_NAME))
ALL_BINS+=$(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $($(BINARY).FULL_FILE_NAME)
$($(BINARY).FULL_FILE_NAME): $($(BINARY).DEP_LIBS)

BINARY:=
LOCATION:=
LIBS:=
```

Ok, in this state, things work fine.  Make handles all the dependencies correctly, and if I touch any of the files, it will correctly "build" only the ones that it has to, and nothing more.  The problem happens when you take the m_prog.mk line from **makefile** and move it to the top of the list, like so:

```
TARGETS:=\
    my_prog.mk \
    Lib1.mk \
    Lib2.mk \
```

The problem seems to be that while its is going through **rules.mk** for **my_prog.mk** it does not yet know what the full library path for Lib1 and Lib2 (they are empty strings).  So in the end, it considers my_prog to be dependent on nothing and it tries to build it out of order.  In this example, you just see it "touch" my_prog first and then the other 2.  Of course, when I have real compiler and linker commands in there, it throws an error.

Back when I simply had the .PHONY targets depend on each other (so my_prog depended on Lib1 and Lib2) life was easy and harmonious.  Now that I can't do that, life became more difficult.

You may say, "heck just put it in the right order!".  Well up to now, this has been handled automatically through make for the end users.  In fact, most customers have been putting things in alphabetical order.  They don't know or care what order they depend on each other.  It would stink to have to tell them to re-order all of that now.  Sorry for the length of this post.  I'd appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you set variables using the := assignment operator, the assignment is evaluated immediately.

If you set variables using just = as the assignment operator, they're evaluated lazily, as late as possible (at the time of actual use).

See http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Flavors.html.

Comment: The problem with this, is that I reuse the variables BINARY, TYPE, LOCATION, & LIBS in each target makefile (I then reset them to empty at the end of rules.mk before including the next customer .mk file).  So if I were to change that to = instead of :=, then I assume it would use the last value set of that variable?  If so then that's not the desired result.  Indeed, I tried it on the above example and I get a circular dependency.

Comment: I'm not used to this way of using make where each makefile is basically a macro that gets expanded each time it's included, and included many times, but it looks like: makefile sets targets and includes top.mk, which includes everything mentioned in targets, each of which sets BINARY/LOCATION/LIBS and includes rules.mk which defines a lot of stuff. And then at the end you define the "all" target. Anyway. You do want BINARY, TYPE, LOCATION, LIBS evaluated immediately, so := is good for them.  But note that ALL_BINS is built using += which uses deferred evaluation already.

Comment: I think you just want to use deferred evaluation for $(BINARY).DEP_LIBS (use = instead of := for that one) and that might be the only change you need to make.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this did not work.  It still tries to "build" the my_prog.exe first.  My suspicion is that it evaluates "$($(BINARY).FULL_FILE_NAME): $($(BINARY).DEP_LIBS)" when it gets to it, and it then goes and evaluates the line you are talking about right away.  So that it behaves no differently.  Thanks though.

Comment: Try adding the -d flag to make invocation to see what order it's considering rules and targets. You'll have to wade through a ton of output but the rule expansion will be in there. I'd expect it to expand those variable references only when evaluating the rule, at the end as a dependency from "all", but I haven't really used this double expansion technique (variable whose value is the name of another variable) that you're using, and maybe that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. The cleanest is probably by using `vpath`. Just modify `rules.mk`:

```
$(BINARY).DEP_LIBS:=$(foreach a,$(LIBS),$(a).so)
ALL_BINS+=$(BINARY)

vpath %.so out/$(LOCATION)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this may be getting closer, but it still not there.  First of all, I made that first line "$(BINARY).DEP_LIBS:=$(foreach a,$(LIBS),lib$(a).so)", but the rest is identical to how you said.  Now, it "builds" libLib1.so and libLib2.so before building out/some/location/my_prog.exe, BUT they are in the root of my project, rather than their respective locations.  Then it goes on to build the 2 libs in their locations.  So as if there are 5 targets instead of 3.  It seems to consider the first 2 dependents of my_prog, but I think the latter 2 are not.

Comment: I'm now convinced that this method will not work.  I can't get it to do anything other than try to build the .so's in the project-root directory.

Is there any slightly less clean ways other than using vpath to do this?